# How to get caret position within contenteditable div with html child elements in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contenteditable, caret, cursor-position

I am working with a contenteditable div that will have the option to have inline html elements such as tags " <p> <font> <br>
" in the text flow.

At certain points I need to grab the caret position(cursor position) of contenteditable div, the caret(cursor) is after an html child element.

i am using following code in javascript for Firefox it works correctly to find caret  position(cursor position) of contenteditable div, but i does not find any solution for Internet Explorer to find caret position (cursor position) as `window.getSelection` is undefined.

```
function getCaretPosition() {
     if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
          var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
          var selectedObj = window.getSelection();
          var rangeCount = 0;
          var childNodes = selectedObj.anchorNode.parentNode.childNodes;
          for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
               if (childNodes[i] == selectedObj.anchorNode) {
                   break;
               }
               if (childNodes[i].outerHTML)
                    rangeCount += childNodes[i].outerHTML.length;
               else if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
                    rangeCount += childNodes[i].textContent.length; 
               }
          }
          return range.startOffset + rangeCount;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

i found that `document.selection;`  works on Internet Expolrer but i don't think it will work for me to find caret position(cursor position) of contenteditable div.

can any one have any work around for me.

in below example my **cursor position is at between 't' and 'w' in <p>two</p>**
`<div contenteditable="true"><p>one<br><b>t|wo</b></p></div>` i suppose to need number 14 in above example as i need to perform some operation at that point i am using this contenteditable div as RichTextbox with my custom style apply to it

Comment: Craet position relative to what? The code looks as though it's trying to get a position within an HTML string representation of the content of the innermost node containing the caret. This is not generally a useful number, so could you say what you intend to do with this caret position?

Comment: Caret position relative to start of my contenteditable div to my current html element inside that contenteditable div
example

        `<div contenteditable="true">  
            <br/>  
            <p>some text</p>  
            <br/>  
            <font>some text</font>  
            <p>current cusrsor position here</p>  
            <br/>  
            <p>some text</p>  
      </div>  `

Comment: I still don't really understand, sorry. If the caret is denoted a pipe in the following HTML, what number do you want, and what are you then going to do with it? `<div contenteditable="true"><p>one<br><b>t|wo</b></p></div>`

Comment: `<div contenteditable="true"><p>one<br><b>t|wo</b></p></div>`

i suppose to need number 14 in above example as i need to perform some operation at that point i am using this contenteditable div as RichTextbox with my custom style apply to it

Comment: @TimDown If you want to insert text at a certain position, keeping the div inner html, then that number is indeed a useful number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi i found answer for internet explorer version 8 or below

```
       var cursorPosition=0;    
       if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            if (range.parentElement() == YourEditableControl) {
                var tmpEle = document.createElement("span");
                YourEditableControl.insertBefore(tmpEle, YourEditableControl.firstChild);
                var tmpRange = range.duplicate();
                tmpRange.moveToElementText(tmpEle);
                tmpRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
                cursorPosition= tmpRange.text.length;
            }
        }
```

above code solve my problem to find current cursor position for IE8 or below version
as window.getSelection() is undifined for IE8 or below and works fine with IE9

so one can use `document.selection` a `selection` object  and `range` object to get current caret or cursor position form `contenteditable` `div` or other control

i hope this will help